# Get user ids of group members

Tags: group

I want to get a list of all users that are members of a group.

I can get the members using getMembers():

```
$members = $group->getMembers();
  foreach ($members as $member) {    
    var_dump($member);
  }
```

But this returns not User objects but GroupMembership objects:

```
object(Drupal\group\GroupMembership)#2609 (1) {
  ["groupContent":protected]=>
  object(Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContent)#2667 (28) {
    ["values":protected]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-default"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      ["type"]=>
```

So how do I get the User IDs from the GroupMembership objects? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself minutes after posting the question... so it goes :).

```
  $members = $group->getMembers();
  foreach ($members as $member) {
    $user = $member->getUser();
    $userids[] = $user->id();
  }
```